# MATLAB vectorization: extracting vector of struct fields from vector of structs

Tags: matlab, vector, struct, vectorization

I have a vector `S` of structs `s`, each struct having a field `x`.

I would like to extract the vector `X` containing the value `x` from each struct in `S`.

Is there a way to do this with vectorization?

Example:

```
s1.x = 42;
s2.x = 87;
s3.x = 24;

S = [s1, s2, s3];
```

I want to get:

```
X = [42, 87, 24]
```

Comment: Something like `X = [S.x]` ?

Comment: @Benoit_11 Brilliant, please submit it as an answer so I can accept it. I had tried `S.x` but was missing the enclosing square brackets.

Comment: Alright haha glad it worked! I'l add a bit more details then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use square brackets to concatenate the content of the field `x` of the structure as follows:

```
X = [S.x]
```

which puts every data associated with the field `x` in a single array.

You could also use the `cat` function to concatenate horizontally:

```
X = cat(2,S.x)
```

Comment: I'm going to be cheeky and ask if you also know how to do the reverse, i.e. given `X`, set all `s.x` in `S` respectively. I tried `[S.x] = X` but I get "too many output arguments".

Comment: I think the function `deal` is what you need:  `S.x = deal(X)`. Is that the case?